# Using solve for a vector parameter in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to solve an equation for variable temp but for different value of the variable delta. 
I want to get my output y to be a vector of size 3, each value corresponding to a value of delta. How do I do this?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
gamma=1.4;
Mi = 2.5;
delta = [9,10,11]
syms temp positive
y = solve(temp == (1/Mi^2) + ( (1/Mi^2) + 0.5*(gamma+1) - temp)*(temp/(1-temp))^(0.5)*tand(delta),temp, 'Real', true);
```

Comment: Please, add definition for `gamma`.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but is it possible something like this can work? `y = arrayfun(@(n) solve(temp == (1/Mi^2) + ( (1/Mi^2) + 0.5*(gamma+1) - temp)*(temp/(1-temp))^(0.5)*tand(delta((n)),temp, 'Real', true), 1:3);` (assuming what you have works for scalar `delta`, which I haven't looked into.

Comment: ilalex: Done, see original post